# function fundamentals

Tags: r, function

I am attempting to write a function to add a suffix to variable names in a data frame.
The code I want to turn into a function: `colnames(dataframe) <- paste0(colnames(dataframe), "_suffix")`

My function:
    `rename <- function(x, y) {colnames(x) <- paste0(colnames(x), y)}`

When I call the function on the data frame I would like to append with a suffix, the data frame does not change. I am sure I am missing some fundamental understanding of how the function should work to append the data frame column names and preserve the data frame name.

Comment: Functions in R have input and output. Only rarely are there "side effects" altering the input. Try `f <- function(x, y){do_stuff; return(x)}` instead maybe.

Comment: Yes that will return the data frame in my console. But how to save those changes into the original name of the data frame?

Comment: Assign your output over the top of the old object:  `df <- fun(df)` Or in your specific case, you probably only need to replace the names `colnames(x) <- fun(x,y)`

Comment: that results in a the creation of a character vector with NULL dimension, this is where I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding

Comment: You might need to give a more complete example so we know what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(4, 5, 6))

rename <- function(x, y) {
  colnames(x) <- paste0(colnames(x), y) 
  return(x)
}
```

As suggested above, you would overwrite the original data frame like so:

```
df <- rename(df, "_suffix")
```